# How to create a text with multiple Font Styles?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I would like to have a text with multiple `FontStyles` on it.

Example (text mixing **bold** and *italic*):

This **is my** *text*!

Normally I could do that like this:

```
<string name="test"><![CDATA[This <b>is my</b> <i><text/i>]]></string>
```

How to do the same using `Text` and `FontStyles` in Compose?

Notes: I don't want to split my text in multiple entries in `strings.xml` file.

Comment: [Use `AnnotatedString.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString.Builder) to build up the `AnnotedString` with your desired styles. AFAIK, you can then use that with `Text()`.

Comment: In this way I will have to split my string in order to use this builder. Or is there any way to do that without splitting my text?

Comment: "In this way I will have to split my string in order to use this builder" -- [`addStyle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString.Builder#addStyle(androidx.compose.ui.text.SpanStyle,%20kotlin.Int,%20kotlin.Int)) does not require you to split your string.

Comment: Thanks!! you are right but I got another problem: internationalization. I can't handle my string using start / end range because these values will change according to the language. @CommonsWare got any another idea? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: "I can't handle my string using start / end range because these values will change according to the language" -- why not? Somehow, you need to know what portions of the string will get formatted. You will need to decide how you want to do that. Perhaps that is data that is stored separately from the string. Perhaps you can use some markup format -- there are a couple of Markdown->`AnnotatedString` examples like [this](https://www.hellsoft.se/rendering-markdown-with-jetpack-compose/) and [this](http://www.zachklipp.com/compose-richtext/richtext-commonmark/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use withStyle() to apply the style. You typically need either SpanStyle or ParagraphStyle.

The example below uses data class collection, which may include bold, italic or whatever is needed. In your case, you would need to build a collection with different styles. In the example below, I use bold style only.

```
@Composable
fun TextStyled() {
    Text(
        buildAnnotatedString {
            withStyle(style = ParagraphStyle(lineHeight = 32.sp)){
                textData.forEach { sd ->
                    if (sd.bold) {
                        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(
                            fontSize = 22.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
                        ) {
                            append(sd.text)
                        }
                    } else {
                        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(
                            fontSize = 22.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight(300)
                        )) {
                            append(sd.text)
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    )
}
```

Another solution is to use regex. Example below replaces all substrings **text** to Text() with FontWeight.Bold.

```
@Composable
fun TextStyled() {
    val text = "This is <b>my text</b> in bold, and this is <b>another text</b> in bold"
    val regex = "<b>(.*?)</b>".toRegex()
    val boldSubstrings = regex.findAll(text).map { it.groupValues[1] }.toList()
    val normalSubstrings = regex.split(text)

    Text(
        buildAnnotatedString {
            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.DarkGray, fontSize = 16.sp)){
                normalSubstrings.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
                    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                        color = Color.DarkGray
                    )
                    ){ append(s) }

                    if (index < boldSubstrings.size) {
                        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(
                            fontSize = 16.sp,
                            color = Color.DarkGray,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                        )
                        ){ append(boldSubstrings[index]) }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

You can find more information about text styling in the official Jetpack Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text).

Answer (score 0):

Usage AnnotatedString and Styling:

The AnnotatedString.Builder() is used to create an instance of AnnotatedString.Builder which allows us to build an AnnotatedString.

Inside a withStyle block, we apply a bold red font style to the argument. You can customize the styling (font size, color, etc.) to your preferences.

```
@Composable
fun StyledMessage(format: String, vararg args: Any) {
    val annotatedString = AnnotatedString.Builder().apply {
        var startIndex = 0

        args.forEachIndexed { index, arg ->
            val placeholder = "%${index + 1}\$"
            val placeholderIndex = format.indexOf(placeholder, startIndex)
            val placeholderEndIndex = placeholderIndex + placeholder.length

            append(format.substring(startIndex, placeholderIndex))

            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = Color.Red)) {
                append(arg.toString())
            }

            startIndex = placeholderEndIndex
        }

        if (startIndex < format.length) {
            append(format.substring(startIndex))
        }
    }.toAnnotatedString()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = annotatedString)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun StyledMessagePreview() {
    StyledMessage("Hello, %1$! You have %2$ new messages.", "Alice", 3)
}
```

[image]